# Control how sympy converts expression to latex

Tags: latex, sympy

I have the following code in `sympy`:

```
from sympy import *
i,j = symbols('i j', cls = Idx)
sum2 = Sum(Sum(Indexed('a',i)*Indexed('b',j),(i,0,2)),(j,0,2))
print(latex(sum2))
```

what I get is:

`\sum_{\substack{0 \leq i \leq 2\\0 \leq j \leq 2}} {a}_{i} {b}_{j}`

which looks like the following:

[image]

I don't want this however. I'd like to see both summation symbols so that it's clear that this is a sum of sums. How can I control how sympy converts the expression to latex?

Comment: Are you sure that's the entire code? I can't replicate it

Comment: sorry yeah that was the wrong code. Please see modifications above it should work now